# Given $F\cos\theta − \mu N = 0$ and $F\sin\theta + N − mg = 0$, find $F$ in terms of $m$, $g$, $\theta$, $\mu$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Given
>
> $$\begin{align}
> F\cos\theta − \mu N \phantom{-}\;\phantom{mg}&= 0 \\
> F\sin\theta + \phantom{\mu}N − mg &= 0 
> \end{align}$$
>
> What is $F$ in terms of $m$, $g$, $\theta$, $\mu$?

Here's what I did:

$$N = mg-F\sin\theta$$
$$F\cos\theta - \mu(mg-F\sin\theta) =0$$
$$F\cos\theta -\mu mg + \mu F\sin\theta = 0$$
$$F\cos\theta + \mu F\sin\theta = \mu mg$$
$$F(\cos\theta + \mu \sin\theta) = \mu mg$$

> $$F = \frac{\mu mg}{\cos\theta + \mu \sin\theta}$$

But, shouldn't the $\mu$ cancel somehow, because the answer is wrong? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please edit for clarity.  Your equations appear to have the $6$ unknowns $F,\theta, u,N,m,g$.  I'm guessing that you know some of these but not others, but why make your readers guess?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your post.

Comment: sorry about that.. Everything is known except for F and N, and the questions asks me to find expression for F in terms of m, g, θ, and u.

Comment: So what is the expected answer?

Comment: No, the `u` should not cancel. Why do you think it should?

Comment: Why do you think your answer is wrong? I cannot find anything wrong with it.

Comment: Use the fact that $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1.$

Answer (score 0):

$$ F\cos \theta − uN = 0 \implies F\cos \theta = uN$$

$$F\sin \theta  + N − mg = 0 \implies F\sin \theta  = -N + mg$$

Square both sides and add them up to get
 $$  F^2 = (uN)^2 + (mg-N)^2$$

Take square root to get $$ F= \sqrt { (uN)^2 + (mg-N)^2}$$

Comment: After you posted your answer, probably, the OP added "the questions asks me to find expression for F in terms of m, g, θ, and u." Could you remove `N` and add `u`?

Comment: Since $N=mg-\sin (\theta )$ we can simply substitute $mg-\sin (\theta)$ for $N$ to remove N.